# Angular 2 startup process - what is happening after we hit http://localhost:4200 in browser

Tags: angular

Can someone help to explain the startup process of Angular2 project?

Let's say, after I use Angular CLI to finish creating a sample project,

1. ng new my-test-app
2. cd my-test-app
3. ng serve

When I hit http://localhost:4200 in browser, what is happening in browser side and server side ?

any resources are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Your browser just starts compiled JS file. Actually you don't have server, because Angular is a client-side framework. Everything works by using JS.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: @Sergey so by default, browser downloads Angular compiler, right ? If I use AOT compile, no compile downloaded

Comment: No. Your Angular CLI compiles index.html and stack of .js files and browser just loads it

Comment: `ng serve`  builds the application and starts a web server. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

Answer (score 1):

This is really abstract questions

**Build**
Angular cli uses web pack internally to build your project. Build means it converts your `scss` to css and typescript to javascript which browser understnads

Then it minigied it and bundle it.

**Run**
Once these browser ready files are available it loads them into a http server which is created on the fly so that you can test your code in the browser

it create a http server in your local machine and load the static web application in the server. you have to read them all to understand what magic happened